# Can't deploy my site to any server,"EventEmitter" is not exported by "__vite-browser-external", imported by "Experience/Utils/Sizes.js"

Tags: javascript, node.js, vite, vercel, eventemitter

I can't deploy website to vercel or any other like site. I get the error message

> "EventEmitter" is not exported by "__vite-browser-external", imported by "Experience/Utils/Sizes.js"

**sizes.js:**

```
import {EventEmitter} from "events"
export default class Sizes extends EventEmitter{
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.width=window.innerWidth;
        this.height=window.innerHeight;
        this.aspect = this.width/this.height;
        this.pixelRatio = Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio,2);
        this.frustrum = 5;

        window.addEventListener("resize",()=>{
            this.width = window.innerWidth;
            this.height = window.innerHeight;
            this.aspect = this.width/this.height;
            this.pixelRatio = Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio,2);
            this.emit('resize')
        })
    }

}
```

also link to git repo:
https://github.com/JakubDomski/JakubDomskiPOrtfolio

I expect it to work, it is my first deploy and I can't figure what is wrong and how to get rid of the problem with eventemmiter

Comment: Did you work this out?